# Can i store my stateful jsx to redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I came across a situation like this, i have some local calculated state and i have a component using that state. And i want to use the exact same component with the calculated state in another route. Using the same code of calculation in another route didn't make sense felt boilerplate, so instead i passed in my component with local state to that route.

It goes like this:

```
let myJsx = (customState) => <Component customState={customState} />

navigateToRoute(someData, myJsx){
  this.props.actions.updateReduxStore(myJsx);
  // ..do something with someData.
  // ..browswerHistory('navigatetoPage');
}

render() {
  return (
    // ..
    <a onClick = {() => {
        let myJsx = myJsx(params);
        this.navigateToRoute(someData, myJsx)
      }
    }
    />
    // .. 
  );
}
```

So i am knowingly passing my jsx into redux store, which is rare, but possible, But are there some risks of doing that way. Is it a good practise ?

Comment: If you only want to be able to use the same calculated local state in another route, then I would recommend simply passing that state to the redux store instead, and avoid passing the JSX altogether. Now you can access that state in any component (provided that it is connected to the redux store), I really can't reason for needing to pass the JSX to the redux store, did you have a specific use case in mind?

Comment: Here's a thread on the same question - https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1248. In short, the answer is no you shouldn't store your JSX in the store, but there are some suggestions on how it could be done.